# Why is my shared library given the suffix ".cpython-33m.so"?

Tags: python, centos, pip, virtualenv, ctypes

I have a pip package that comes with a C library. The python module can't find the shared library. I noticed that it was given the name

```
librebound.cpython-33m.so
```

after the installation on CentOS, whereas on all other platforms it is just called `librebound.so`. Why is it getting the suffix `cpython-33m.so` and how can I prevent it?

I'm installing this in a virtual environment. Various version are:

Python 3.3.5

Virtualenv 13.0.3

pip 7.0.3

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/ ?

Comment: `imp.get_suffixes()` returns the list of supported suffixes. In Python 3.4 on Ubuntu Linux this returns `[('.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'rb', 3), ('.cpython-34m.so', 'rb', 3), ('.abi3.so', 'rb', 3), ('.so', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'r', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]`. As linked above, PEP 3149 ABI tags have been used for many years now -- since Python 3.2.

Comment: See [What's New in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.2.html#pep-3149-abi-version-tagged-so-files) (2011).

Comment: Fantastic, that helps a lot. Do you have a reference for the "standard way" of finding the path to a shared library?